# Any audio noise reduction technique for android?

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager, noise-reduction

I am very new to android development. I am developing an app which does voice recording.In that I would like to remove the noise in the recorded audio.I know there are in-built options but would like to try any custom **noise reduction algorithm** or **technique**.

Is there any **noise reduction technique** for audio?

Comment: Sure. If you google for "acoustic noise suppression algorithm" you'll find plenty of scientific papers on the subject.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for your comment. Is there any already build algorithm for android like jar file.

Answer (score 0):

check it out:

[NoiseSuppressor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/NoiseSuppressor.html)

It look Android have a API for that.